# Database won't update in Unity Editor with Firebase

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to follow the guides and help articles on Firebase's website concerning Unity's setup with the realtime database. Unfortunately I am having a hard time getting my data to sync or be added -- for some reason the database not recognizing the data I am trying to put in as a test.

Here is what I have to setup the whole thing:

```
public static DatabaseManager instance = null;

public string userID;
public string userDisplayName;

private DatabaseReference dbReference;

private void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = this;
    else if (instance != this)
        Destroy(gameObject);

    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("URLOfAppHere");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12FileName("AppFileHere.p12");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorServiceAccountEmail("account.gserviceaccount.com");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12Password("password");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorAuthUserId("1234");

    dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
}

private void Start()
{

    CreateDataEntry("Testing User", "1234");
}

public void CreateDataEntry(string _displayName, string _userID)
{

    dbReference.Child("users").Child(_userID).SetValueAsync("test");
}
```

My current rules set in the project are these:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I also tried the default one. Unfortunately, neither of which works. I then tried to set it to public but again didn't work.

Any ideas what is going here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue you have is that your editordatabaseurl is not specified in url form.

Check out:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start#configuring_the_sdk_for_the_unity_editor

It should be:

```
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseio.com/");
```

Your service account setup also looks wrong because "account.gserviceaccount.com" is not a valid email address.  I would erase the "p12" settings you have in code and turn on [public access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules) for your database to see if that works.  Then if that works, try to follow the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start#optional_editor_setup_for_restricted_access) to set up service account access.

--------------EDIT--------------------

OK I just realized you might have intentionally redacted that info.
Another gotcha with the P12 setup is that the service account you set up should have the proper permission (project editor).

...And if you set the p12 file path, Firebase will use the service account and fail even if you set public access.  so - remove any p12 values altogether and try again with public access to remove p12 configuration as a possibility.

Comment: "OK I just realized you might have intentionally redacted that info."

Yes at first I didn't then, I had to redact the information. It looks literally like the format in the article.

"Another gotcha with the P12 setup is that the service account you set up should have the proper permission (project editor)."

Can I change its permission from the IAM menu as an Editor? As I don't have the option to play with the permissionf or it at all.


What do you mean with file path for the p12? I didn't put a file path, just the file name with ".p12" at the end.

Comment: I mean comment out the line "FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12FileName" and turn on public access.  If this works you know its probably due to a bad service account setup.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I did just that and public accounts work. It seems the testing account isn't working. That said, I followed the steps in [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start) any ideas what might have gone wrong? I even gave the account editor permission (asked owner to do so).

And does this interfere with normal sign in? Or just the service account? Anyway to fix the account? Or do I create a new one?

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Try not calling SetEditorAuthUserId.  If set, firebase will attempt to impersonate that user along with his restrictions.  Also double check your p12 password (the default is "notasecret")

Comment: I finally got the database to save information, the problem is it works when I use real data from an exported project on Android. But in the editor it doesn't work at all. I also saw in other questions that Firebase doesn't support in Editor testing which is weird and nonesensical approach. Might that be case? That it isn't quite correctly in the editor?

Comment: Firebase only supports the realtime database and storage in the editor.  But it does not support Auth.  So the easiest thing to do is test both using public access on a project that has no valuable private information.  Or if you can get the service account set up, that will also work for the realtime database.

Comment: I see. Strange system to be honest and feel quite messy. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: The more feedback we get about getting better editor support, the more likely we are to fix it -- so I truly welcome any feedback you have here.  Please voice your opinion in our group chat: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk or you can also file a support ticket request here: 
https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea @Benjamin Wulfe, honestly I didn't know you are part of Firebase and thought you were just a regular StackOverflow user. I have submitted a report on your website and hopefully it will help you guys :).

Comment: This works just fine for me: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start#optional_editor_setup_for_restricted_access I use the default rules, but it should work regardless of what you write in rules, because this uses an admin service account in editor mode.

Comment: @GaziAlankus How can I test other rules if the editor is always an administrator?

Comment: @Oli As far as I remember, you can't do that from the Unity Editor.